# Cannot open file "/tests/bootstrap.php"

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

Recently I started to use PHPUnit on my project and so far everything works perfectly, I can launch my tests just fine.

But following a potential mishandling on my part when I launch my tests here is the message that appears, preventing me from playing them:

> `Cannot open file "/tests/bootstrap.php".`

FYI, I have not touched a file with this name, I have never heard of it before.

Has anyone ever encountered not opening the file `/tests/bootstrap.php`? Do you have any idea where it comes from?

Comment: That file sets up the testing environment. If you don't have any special setup, just point it to `config/bootstrap.php` to let symfony load the standard `test` environment.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank's a lot !

Comment: @VincentL.: Please take a short moment of your time and answer your own question, e.g. what for you the actual problem was and what did it solve. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved !

I don't have any special setup, just point it to config/bootstrap.php to let symfony load the standard test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Edit *phpunit.xml*. Set bootstrap =

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     bootstrap="./web/core/tests/bootstrap.php" colors="true"
```

Run it

> vendor/bin/phpunit web/modules/custom/mymodule/tests/src/Kernel/WwgRiverLoadFileTest.php